# Catalogs for type K stars and their planetary systems?

Tags: star, resource-request, star-catalogues, main-sequence

I am doing data collection on all [type K stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-type_main-sequence_star), and their planetary system so I may develop an algorithm for a planetary formation simulation with the [Unity game engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)).

Where could such a catalog of stars be found?

#### Related

- [Is there anywhere I can find some kind of database on all known stars and their properties (mass, surface temperature, radius, and luminosity)?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8291/is-there-anywhere-i-can-find-some-kind-of-database-on-all-known-stars-and-their)
- [Looking for star database](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/18191/looking-for-star-database?noredirect=1&lq=1) (a bit outdated)

Comment: And do you need the data of all K-stars which have known companions or all K-type stars, irrespective of known planets orbiting them?

Comment: Needs more focus. We need to know exactly what you need to know about these K-stars (other than a spectral type).

Comment: @ProfRob Mr. Anderson also mentioned "planetary systems", so I am assuming that this is another boundary condition, but I am just guessing.

Comment: @B--rian yes, so probably just a simple interrogation of the exoplanets archive might do - it is a bit unclear what's wanted.

Comment: @B--rian I think this is a little outdated as Gaia DR2 is available, etc

Answer (score 1):

There are many [star catalogues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_catalogue#Full-sky_catalogues_(in_chronological_order)), and from your question I cannot easily tell which would be the best one for you. You probably need one which contains positions of the star and their spectral type, maybe further properties as well.

Since you mentioned planetary systems, I think you might actually want to look at [NASA Exoplanet archive](https://exoplanetarchive.ipac.caltech.edu/) (and filter it for K-type central stars).